# SQL - using date table to calculate days employee last worked?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that shows when an Employee last worked. It looks like the below

```
EMPID           Sickness          Date
23333             N            01-FEB-2018
23333             N            02-FEB-2018
23333             N            10-FEB-2018
23333             N            11-FEB-2018
```

What I would like to do is join to a date table and add an additional column which shows the date in which an employee would have been out of work >= than 5 days. An example output based on the above would look like this

```
EMPID           Sickness          NewDate              AbsFlagAdded
23333             N            01-FEB-2018              0
23333             N            02-FEB-2018              0
23333             N            03-FEB-2018              0
23333             N            04-FEB-2018              0
23333             N            05-FEB-2018              0
23333             N            06-FEB-2018              0
23333             N            07-FEB-2018              1
23333             N            08-FEB-2018              0
23333             N            09-FEB-2018              0
23333             N            10-FEB-2018              0
23333             N            11-FEB-2018              0
```

The AbsFlagAdded is marked as 1 for the 7th of February as this was the 5th consecutive day that EMPID 23333 had off work based on the original table.

Is anyone able to help out with this? I haven't really used Date tables before. Appreciate any help

Jess

Comment: If im not mistaken you can use the function called DATEDIFF(), in the first column, and if its more than five days (in this case, yes it has been more than 5 days, 8 to be exact, then add a flag), you can do this with the select (case) statements

Comment: I have used DATEDIFF before and not sure how this would work as the WorkDates are on separate rows?

Comment: Give me a minute, ill try sorting out an example with sql fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Here's one using using `datediff` with `case`:

```
select t.empid, d.dt, 
       case when datediff(day, max(t.dt), d.dt) = 5 then 1 else 0 end as absflaggadded
from dates d
    left join yourtable t on d.dt >= t.dt
group by t.empid, d.dt
order by d.dt
```

- [Online Demo](https://rextester.com/YPV3295)

This uses `dates` as the date table.  Notice the `outer join` check -- this ensures you get the matching results instead of `null` values if you used equals.

Comment: instead of just checking if its 5 it should check if its > 5 since if its then add 1 per each 5 days (if i understood the question correctly)